# Woocommerce send unique pdf

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have developed a code to send tickets (PDF files) of a specific product in the order confirmation. I place the PDFs in a folder (Tickets) on the server after the purchase is completed. The code retrieves the corresponding number of PDFs based on the quantity of the item, sends them in the confirmation email, and then moves them to another folder (UsedTickets).

Is the code well-written? Are there any issues if there are multiple purchases happening simultaneously?

Thank you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'add_pdf_attachment_to_wc_email', 10, 3 );

function add_pdf_attachment_to_wc_email( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
  // Check if the email is 'customer_completed_order' and if the product in the cart is 8059.
  if ( $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' && $order && $order->get_item_count() ) {
    $pdf_files = glob( get_template_directory() . '/Tickets/*.pdf' );
    $pdf_count = 0;
    $pdf_attachments = array(); // Creating an empty list for the names of the PDF files that will be attached.
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
      if ( $item->get_product_id() === 8059 ) {
        $pdf_count += $item->get_quantity();
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $item->get_quantity(); $i++ ) {
          $pdf_path = $pdf_files[ $pdf_count - $item->get_quantity() + $i % count( $pdf_files ) ];
          $pdf_attachments[] = $pdf_path; // Adding the PDF file to the list of attachments.
        }
      }
    }
    // Moving the PDF files to the 'UsedTickets' folder.
    foreach ( $pdf_attachments as $pdf_path ) {
      $pdf_filename = basename( $pdf_path );
      $new_path = get_template_directory() . '/UsedTickets/' . $pdf_filename;
      if ( rename( $pdf_path, $new_path ) ) {
        error_log( 'PDF successfully moved to UsedTickets folder.: ' . $pdf_filename );
      } else {
        error_log( 'An error occurred while moving the PDF to the UsedTickets folder: ' . $pdf_filename );
      }
      $attachments[] = $new_path; // Adding the PDF file to the email attachments.
    }
  }
  return $attachments; // Returning the updated list of attachments.
}
```

Send tickets/pdf's and save order

Comment: If you're asking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I think you're in a wrong place.

Comment: Np :), looks like you've posted in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286157/woocommerce-send-unique-pdf). You might want to check [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what's on-topic here and so on.